# Is it necessary to activate automatic reboot for unattended upgrade on a webserver?

Tags: server, upgrade, webserver

I’m running a Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS web server. My apps run with docker.

Is it necessary to activate `automatic reboot` for `unattended upgrade` on a web server by setting `Unattended-Upgrade::Automatic-Reboot` to true in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`?

If I don’t activate `automatic reboot`, the upgrades won’t apply?

Is it save to reboot a production web server?

Comment: Knowing the version of Ubuntu you are using will maybe give a better answer.

Comment: @David  22.04 stable version

Comment: Not sure what you mean by stable version 22.04 has been considered and is stable since release. 22.04.1 is the version will the first large update applied.

Comment: @David Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I don't work with IT production, so this is my personal (and not purely professional) take on the subject.*

There are rather few packages that require a reboot to be applied. The ones I can think of are:

- Kernel upgrades (that are not livepatched)
- `libc6`, `openssl` and `dbus` upgrades *(if you know others, please let me know)*

It is perfectly fine to let these packages upgrade without rebooting, and then rebooting the server whenever it's appropriate. For a production server (depending on its role), I would reboot during a service window.

I don't believe automatically rebooting a production server is ever a good idea (unless you have a fixed service window for it). For instance, I'm booting my own server every sunday night (if it's needed) - but at least I know precisely if and when it's rebooted.

If a production server is critical to operation, I would assume there is some *clustering/load balancing/failover* mechanism in place (in addition to a robust backup strategy) - but this is another discussion altogether.

There is also a reason professional livepatching services exist (like Canonical Livepatch, KernelCare etc.). This is exactly to prevent disruption of critical services.

Comment: I *do* work with production servers that span across the globe and your answer is correct. Even for systems that have zero "official" maintenance window, there's nothing stopping boxes from being removed from a load balancer, restarted, and re-added 

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! 